# PHP automatic redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem that has been troubling me for awhile. I have this php page that redirects automatically and I can't figure out why. I have even put a die() function at the top of said page, but it still continues to redirect. Even if I delete everything and put this single print function in the Signin.php page it still continues to redirect to another page. Also, it only happens for this particular url www.example.com/Signin.php and not others.

*To note I don't have a .htaccess file

```
print "hello world";
```

Comment: do you have header functions in your code ? does it still happen if you rename your file

Comment: @Buddhi741 I have renamed it and have deleted everything but a print line, it still redirects. It is super confusing seeing as how it doesn't have header or redirect functions on the page.

Comment: ok whats your dev environment if might be because you have some old code haunting you. eg .htaccess on parent directory

Comment: Dev environment is vagrant. Am gonna try deleting everything and starting from scratch. I don't thing I have any .htaccess files but I will try to grep it.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: no not so sure about whats going on. iv not used vagrant boxes extensively. id suggest adding vagrant in the tags so some one with more experience can help

Comment: Clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in online server, usually **.htaccess** file will be hidden over there. Change settings to show all hidden files and check whether the **.htaccess** file have something written for redirection.

Comment: Usually it is stated that .htaccess files are in the root of web directory, can you elaborate where that might be. The directory is the default apache /var/www. Thanks again.